# Using EF with different read and write db servers

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-4

I’m considering using Entity Framework for a project.  I’m trying to understand how I can configure EF to work with a database environment that is configured with a read server and a write server.
All updates to the write server will be replicated over to the read servers.

My questions are:

1. Do I need to generate different data models for the two environments?
2. Can I reuse the same data model?
3. Is there something built into EF itself that will allow for this?

Thanks

Comment: I assume the write server should read as well, or do you always only write new data? Anyways, EF would be a good choice if it involves CRUD operations. The best choice for reading greatly depends on all kinds of details. Like: are there different databases (different scheme), what tiers are there?

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the same model because you can instantiate an ObjectContext with any connection string you like. AFAIK you can even switch out the connection later, so you can use two different server connections with the same EntityContext.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the data models are identical, then no.
2. Du to #1 being no, #2 is automatically yes.
3. EF just requires you pass it a different connection string

However...

I'm not really sure how you intend to make this work.  You will lose virtually benefit of an ORM, you can't do change tracking, and you will have a lot of problems not reading from the write model.

Frankly, I'm not sure how you could make this work with any ORM.

Comment: Maybe an ORM is not the correct solution for the problem. That is one of the things I'm trying to determine.

Given that there is one write server and multiple read servers, it might make more sense for me to either use EntLib or just roll my own data access layer.

I am looking at EF, to see if I can avoid writting a REST service, and just use OData on top of the EF code to expose the operations needed to the web client.

thanks for the input and answers.